# Can One Link Invoke Two Ajax Updates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 page that has two partial views, one for `Items in Bucket A`, and one for `Items in Bucket B` (simplified for discussion... there's significant logic to rendering each bucket, and that logic is different between the buckets).

I have a link on the page that lets me move an item from `Bucket A` to `Bucket B`.  Once that link is clicked, I have to refresh the partial views for `Items in Bucket A`, and the partial view for `Items in Bucket B`.

I can refresh one or the other using Ajax, like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Move to B", "_BucketB", "Home", new { item = Model.Item }, 
new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "divForBucketB",
    HttpMethod = "Post", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
```

How can I approach the problem of also refreshing `divForBucketA` when the ActionLink is clicked?

**UPDATE**

The HTML that goes into `divForBucketA` needs to be generated using the appropriate View and Controller.  The changes to the `div` contents are too significant to be processed on the client in JavaScript (other than perhaps invoking another Ajax call... can that be done?)

Comment: i think your better off ditching the `AjaxOptions`, and just roll your own ajax with jQuery. That way you can do `onclick=myfunction()`, where `myfunction()` fires 2 ajax calls and updates the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it with jQuery.  Obviously you would need to fix the Url.Action calls and this does assume that the BucketA controller method returns a PartialView.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mybutton").click(function() {
     $.get(@Url.Action("Index", "BucketA"), function (data) {
        $('#bucketA').html(data);
     });
     $.get(@Url.Action("Index", "BucketB"), function (data) {
        $('#bucketB').html(data);
     });

     e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "fix the Url.Action calls"?

Comment: @Url.Action("Index", "BucketA") <- would only work if you had a controller called BucketAController with a method called Index which returned a PartialView().  You would want to provide the correct parameters to the @Url.Action call

Answer (score 1):

You could use the AjaxOptions `OnComplete` or `OnSuccess` (depending on your needs) to specify a Javascript function to call after the Ajax call finishes to perform any additional processing (like updating the other bucket).

Comment: The contents for "Bucket A" need to be generated by the appropriate controller... it's not appropriate to just do that in JavaScript on the client.  I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: In that case, you could just add an onclick handler for the link and have it call a javascript function that starts two ajax calls, one to update each div.

Comment: My above comment would mean removing the Ajax.ActionLink and just making it a regular link that you set up an onclick handler for.